# Migrate a binary framework with dependencies from CocoaPods to SPM or XCFramework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have inherited a Framework Xcode project with a dozen or so dependencies. Historically it has been distributed as a binary framework via CocoaPods. We now need to support distribution via SPM, or at least distribution as an XCFramework. I have spent hours googling and experimenting, with no luck. I can attempt to build an XCFramework with this:

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme MyFramework \
-destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
-archivePath "archives/ios_simulator.xcarchive" \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
-workspace MyFramework.xcworkspace

xcodebuild archive \
-scheme MyFramework \
-destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
-archivePath "archives/ios_devices.xcarchive" \
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
-workspace MyFramework.xcworkspace

xcodebuild \
-create-xcframework \
-framework ./archives/ios_devices.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework \
-framework ./archives/ios_simulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework \
-output ./archives/MyFramework.xcframework
```

This appears to build successfully; but the built binary framework does not contain its dependencies. This would be okay if they could be added with SPM in the project that's using the framework. But for frameworks added with SPM which are source repositories, rather than binary frameworks, Xcode reports "No such module" when I build the project. The offending frameworks are CocoaLumberjack, KeychainAccess, RealmSwift, and ZIPFoundation. In case that's helpful at all.

I have tried changing the embedding settings, rebuilding a new framework project without using CocoaPods, making a package and adding it locally, and a long list of various tweaks I have forgotten.

Any help or direction will be appreciated. This is the first time I'm doing something like this; so, I may be missing something simple and fundamental.

Answer (score 3):

Use a wrapper target to wrap both the binary target and its dependencies. See the [FirebaseAnalytics example](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Package.swift#L284).

Comment: This is the most common reference I see for something like dependencies in a swift package with a binary product. But I still get the "No such module" message for all the source dependencies. I'll see if I can put together an example.